# What if all answers to my question are bad?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

I asked a question in stackoverflow and the answers to my questions are bad. What I mean with `bad`? Answer is irrelated; answerer makes an assumption about the issue, and answers according it. Then everybody starts upvoting the answer. **Although I clearly stated in my question problem is not because of that**, it seems community approve the answer by voting :)

In addition, I am aware of that irrelevant answers may help someone. However, since I cannot find answer to my question yet, I do not accept any answer. My **accept rate** will fall eventually.

What should I do in this case? Downvote all? Flag as "not an answer"? Or something else?

P.S I searched this topic a lot. I could not find anything what I am looking for.

Comment: The question in question seems to be [Missing debug toolbar in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818319/missing-debug-toolbar-in-symfony2).  It's often helpful to have something concrete to discus.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Don't worry about accept rate. If none of the answers help, then don't accept any of them. Flag any comments nagging about accept rate as "not constructive".
2. If the answer is wrong, down-vote it and/or leave a comment explaining why it's wrong.
3. If your question is unclear, leading to confusion and incorrect answers, then **edit** your question to clarify and improve it.

Comment: +1 for option 3. Consider that your question may not be clear to those not capable of reading your mind.

Comment: @Oded yeah, I just edited my question and made it bold :)

Comment: @seferov - It might still not be prominent enough, or it may be obscured. Having said that, many people do not read the whole question - in these cases, pointing out that you have said that in a comment is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

One other thing... you can always place [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) on the question later to attract more attention to it.

Also, with a bounty, you can add additional information about what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: I clicked the close icon in your image :(

Comment: for some reason, "foo the bar so that I can baz the qux" cracked me up. I'm going to use that now.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be a lack of specificity in your *question*. Bad answers are sometimes indicative of bad questions.

You say "What might be the reason?" Well, I imagine a lot of things "*might*" be the reason. That's not very useful.

You don't provide a lot of information to the user. Certainly, not enough to reproduce the problem. Here are some quotes from the answers: "There might be a CSS issue...", "...it might be the problem that cache is not warmed up...", etc. The answerers are *guessing*, because they don't have enough information to adequately diagnose the problem.

Beef up your question. Good questions are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that. You are right

Comment: Consistently bad answers are *nearly always* indicative of a bad question. Related: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html